# Check if a string is among the values of a map that has vector of strings as values

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, stdstring, stdmap

I want to check if a string is among the values of a map which holds vectors of strings as values

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<string>> ClusterDescription;
std::map<std::string, std::vector<string>> clusterDescription;


std::vector<string> vec1 = {"11", "22", "33"};
std::vector<string> vec2 = {"44", "55"};
std::vector<string> vec3 = {};

std::string key1 = "1";
std::string key2 = "2";
std::string key3 = "3";

clusterDescription.insert(std::make_pair(key1, vec1));
clusterDescription.insert(std::make_pair(key2, vec2));
clusterDescription.insert(std::make_pair(key3, vec3));

std::string ID = "44";

for (ClusterDescription::iterator it = clusterDescription.begin(); it != clusterDescription.end(); ++it)
{
    std::vector<std::string> clusterMembers = it->second;
    if(std::find(clusterMembers.begin(), clusterMembers.end(), ID) != clusterMembers.end())
    {
        std::cout<< " I received an msg, from the wrong head "<< std::endl;      //FIXME:
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<< " I have not been included in any cluster yet "<< std::endl;        //FIXME:
        std::cout<< " sending joinmode msg "<< std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Here the code works fine for the values: `11`, `22`, `33`. But it fails for the other cases. What am I missing?

Comment: You are breaking out of the for loop after the first iteration, so only the first element of the map is ever analyzed.

Comment: @cross: Why do you not expect it? That _is_ what your code does, and all we can see is your code not what you instead wanted your code to be. Therefore it is impossible to divine your intention by reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to know if you can *find* the string in *any of* the vectors in the cluster? Use standard algorithms `any_of` and `find`:

```
bool stringIsContained(const ClusterDescription &cluster, const std::string &s)
{
  return std::any_of(
    begin(cluster), end(cluster), [&s](ClusterDescription::const_reference item)
    {
      return std::find(begin(item.second), end(item.second), s) != end(item.second);
    }
  );
}
```

Using standard algorithms where possible is idiomatic C++.

---

To address why your original code doesn't work the way you'd want it to:

You have a `break` in both branches of the conditional, which means the loop body will only ever execute for the first string-vector pair in the cluster.

If you simply remove the breaks, it will execute once for each string-vector pair in the cluster. Since each of the branches has an output statement, you will get one for each such pair.

If your intention is to search the whole data structure and only output at the end, you have to store the result of the search somewhere and only do output outside the loop. Which is pretty much what my code above does, except the loops are hidden in the algorithms. The result is "stored" in the return values, and you can simply act once on the final return value of the function.